# What useful information can be delivered from this information?

Tags: charts, analytics

I have data in the following format : `userid , linkname, number of times linked clicked`

As an example :

```
1234,stackoverflow,1
1234,google,3
```

One useful piece of information is a pie chart where each slice represents a page view with pages that have greater number of views having a bigger slice. So if a user see's that a certain link is quite a large link could decide to bookmark that link as its frequently used.

Are there other useful data that can be generated from this dataset ?

Comment: I found some good answers to this question over at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/how-to-graphically-represent-click-data

Comment: I found some good answers to this question over at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/how-to-graphically-represent-click-data

Answer (score 0):

This is backwards, like you have a solution looking for a problem.

Instead of wondering what charts you can build from a given data set, you need to ask what information the users want to derive from the data. Once you know what questions the users are asking, you need to find the data and present it in such a way that it provides the information.

So, `what are the top ten most clicked links` would possibly lead to a bar or column chart that shows a ranked series of the number of clicks and their respective page urls. And to make this chart useful and easy to read, it would most definitely not be a pie chart.

Data visualisation is a bit more complex than building charts for charts' sake.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't think this answers my question, perhaps this was the wrong stack-exchange site to use.